# fsck is taking a lot of time?(buffer I/O error)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, busybox, fsck, smartctl

I had a irregular powercut 4-5 times in a row within an hour. My ubuntu suddenly went into busy box mode and showed there are errors on /dev/sda5.

I then tried:
`fsck /dev/sda5 -y`

It has taken a lot of time more than an hour and still forcing rewrite. It seems that a lot of blocks are being repaired.

Can someone describe what is going on or suggest any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, what has probably happened is that you had the head hit the hard drive, or something similar.

Your best bet is probably to replace /dev/sda altogether.  Note that the errors may not be restricted to sda5, but may get all your partitions.

(I had this happen recently to a 5 terabyte drive.  Painful.)

In my experience, the "rewrite" option doesn't help.  And if you say no, fsck just terminates.  I would recommend mounting all the partition read-only and copying the data to other media (i.e. the new drive I'm recommending you acquire).

It is possible to do a "bad block scan" using the `e2fsck` option `-c`.  On the other hand, it isn't supposed to be needed on a modern hard disk.

Comment: After completing the fsck scan, ubuntu booted and prompted for a password and it went to a password loop, still asking for password many times after right password has been provided, then I reinstalled the ubuntu and checked the hard drive health using smartmontools, it passed. I also doubt the hard drive health.

Comment: I would agree that any drive that requires "sector recovery" should be replaced. It's been found in large data centres that upwards of 30% of drives eventually fail having given absolutely no prior SMART indication, so don't trust "passed according to smartmontools" as meaning the drive is trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: always run `fsck` after a abrupt shutdown, reboot, or disconnection of a drive. What causes *serious* damage to the filesystem structure is continuing to use it once it's already slightly damaged.

Long answer…

On its own "a long time" does not necessarily indicate a physical problem with the drive.

But it might, depending on what exactly you mean by *a lot of blocks are being repaired*: unreadable blocks being remapped indicates a potential drive fault, but blocks being cross-linked into multiple files is just a logical error with the filesystem. (Serious loss of data, but not cause to throw away the drive.)

I recently had to run `fsck` on a 5TiB drive connected via a USB-2 interface on an older machine, and even with *no* sector errors, it still took a very long time.

I ran `strace` to see why `fsck.ext4` was so slow, and the answer was obvious: it was issuing a separate `pread` syscall for each 4KiB block - effectively, one for each of the 10M in-use inodes.

I went to bed after waiting for more than an hour, and it had completed successfully when I got up the next morning; somewhere between 1 and 9 hours after it started.

In my case I trusted that it wasn't a drive problem because (a) there had been a recent hard reboot, (b) the only reported errors were the free inode and free block counts being lower than they should have been, and (c) I'd been merging duplicate files when the reboot occurred — essentially, just deleting lots of stuff, and changing existing directory entries.

Fortunately I hadn't written new stuff as well, so there were no cross-linked files.